# Firefox mobile prevents input inside iframe

Tags: javascript, android, html, firefox, iframe

I'm trying to realize a fixed floating panel over my site that loads an iframe with a login form. It seems to work fine with every mobile browser except for firefox mobile (firefox desktop works fine) that prevents every kind of input. 
When I try to write something (with stock keyboard on android 6.0.1) in a form inside an iframe it seems to buffer the text but nothing appear on input element. Moreover when I click on any input field outside my iframe, the whole text written before get attached in this field.

```
<img id="logo" src="icons/logo-little-BLACKBACK.png">
<div id="logingeneric" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="generic-dialog">
        <div class="generic-content">
            <div class="generic-header">
                <h4 class="text-center">Login</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="generic-body">
                <form class="form center-block" action="Home.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="email-field" name="username" class="form-control input-lg input-field" placeholder="Email" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="password-field" name="password" class="form-control input-lg input-field" placeholder="Password" type="password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Accedi</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="generic-footer">
                <span class="pull-right" id="registrati">
                    <a href="Register.php">Registrati</a>
                </span>
                <span class="pull-left">
                    <a href="RecoverPassword.php">Password dimenticata?</a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the body of the page loaded inside my iframe. How can I avoid this strange behaviour of Firefox mobile?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I got a solution. In our case we override the onResize event that is triggered on every input focus in order to correctly scale the floating panel. This led to a focus lost on every "zoom on focus" on firefox (a bug maybe?).
The solution is to avoid panel scaling if an input element is focused.

Comment: I have the exact same issue and this helped me a lot! How exactly did you implement "avoid panel scaling if an input element is focused"?

Comment: In my case a scale function was used on input container. Removing "scale" from onResize fixed our problem. Anyway we use onScroll to correctly scale panel on mobile (when you use pinch to zoom, you scroll the content, so onScroll can be used like a sort of "onZoom" event.)
I hope this will be helpful for you